# Undo bounty? Perhaps a bug on interface of accepted answer

Tags: bug, bounty, accepted-answer

Can I "undo" the bounty? I click "useful" because [the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33533/7505) was "goodwill", but I not click as "my accepted answer"... Now the system used it as "accepted for bounty", but it is wrong (!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the system granted the bounty to that answer under the standard bounty rules, which state that if *you* do not designate an answer for the bounty within the deadline (plus about a half day grace period), then the highest-voted answer will get *half* the bounty.

No users (including moderators) can change this.

For details and more information, please consult the [StackOverflow FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Thanks! Well, let see FAQs... OK, I think there are rules for avoid opportunism of: **1)** self-use of the bounty, promoting your questions.
**2)** "bounty hunters", that answer "blabla .. anything" and get bounty if nobody really answers, by automatic awarding, with some help (only 2 votes) of friends. Opportunism 1 is avoided by the "bounty not refunded to the bounty starter" rule, ok. But, about *opportunism-2*? there are a more defensive rule? There are an internal algorithm to check group of users voting in themselves?? &nbsp; (it is just a hypothesis, I think not the case on my question)

Comment: (1) The site actually *encourages* using bounties for promoting one's own questions. You can even get several badges for doing this ([Promoter](http://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/46/promoter) and [Benefactor](http://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/47/benefactor)). (2) Yes, there are internal checks on using bounties artificially to exchange reputation among cliques of users. The details are not made public. Also, moderators can review summaries of bounties in order to find patterns of abuse.